# Is there a way to have internal registries for Go like NPM has Verdaccio?

Tags: go, package, verdaccio

Although, this question is not related to nodejs, I am adding those fields, in case people familiar with handling NPM packages on private registries like Verdaccio can help guide or answer this question in a way which might be language agnostic.

From what I know, for private registries for TS/JS/Node, NPM will first query Verdaccio, which when then route to the public npm registry in case the package is not found.

What my issue is, that I feel package management in Go (Golang) is not as comprehensive as it is for NPM. Especially if you have packages on a private gitlab/github server, it becomes extremely messy, with a lot of configuration changes. There need to be code changes in a lot of cases, overall I have been struggling, and have wasted hours upon hours migrating code and fixing imports. I tried to find answers regarding this, but most of them just point to installing directly from Gitlab.

My question is, is there a way, where I can upload these packages to a private repository, which `go get` will refer to first and if it does not find a package there refer to the public repository instead? This problem becomes two-fold if for example I have to refer to different packages held in different private repositories on gitlab + github.

For example:

I want my code to look like:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    mpp "myprivatepackage"
)
```

instead of

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    mpp "gitlab.com/myprivategitlab/myprivatepackage"
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, of course not. And asking for tooling would be OT here anyway.

Comment: Go does not have registries by design. However, you can use any domain under your control to resolve import paths to source code repositories. See [Remote import paths](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Remote_import_paths).

Comment: I don't know what would be so "obvious" about it @Volker, it just shows bad language design, you could have answered like Peter instead. 
I already tried some version of remote import paths, but I think I will try to push resolve certain domains to source code instead thanks

Comment: The import path is not something like a trivial name you substitute, it's _the_ identifier of a package. And if you consider how packages work "bad language design" you might want to avoid Go where packages and how they work are central. Node is different here and might fit your taste better.

Comment: Wait, what? All you need to have is a ssh-agent running, and Bob's your uncle. And you are seriously accusing Ken Thompson (yes, THAT Ken Thompson), Rob Pike and Robert Griesemer of bad language design because you do not like the way dependencies are declared and compare it to a package management that is so broken that a single developer made it impossible to compile react components for hours? Wow... Just wow...